# Inconsistent "LoadError" behavior with 'lib' namespacing/autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

We have just created a new file in 'lib' that has spawned a series of headaches involving load errors.

/lib/response_set.rb:

```
module MyCompany
  class ResponseSet < Array
    ...
  end
end
```

/spec/lib/response_set_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyCompany::ResponseSet do
  describe "..." do
    ...
  end
end
```

Running this spec in Rspec gives us the following error when it gets to the first 'describe':

```
/Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /Users/my_stuff/projects/my_project/lib/response_set.rb to define ResponseSet (LoadError)
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/backward_compatibility.rb:20:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-expectations-2.5.0/lib/rspec/expectations/backward_compatibility.rb:6:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/my_stuff/projects/my_project/spec/lib/response_set_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `map'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:386:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/rspec-core-2.5.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

HOWEVER! We have been using many other files for a long long time that have identical structure. For example, here's another one that has been working fine since it was created:

/lib/smart_set.rb

```
module MyCompany
  class SmartSet < Array
    ...
  end
end
```

And /spec/lib/smart_set_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyCompany::SmartSet do
  describe "..." do
    ...
  end
end
```

This file has the identical structure but causes no problems at all.

ResponseSet ( the problem class ) apparently has loading issues for no discernable reason. In the rails console, the first time I try to create one, I get an error, but then I can create one afterwards:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.4)
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :001 > rs = MyCompany::ResponseSet.new
LoadError: Expected /Users/my_stuff/projects/my_project/lib/response_set.rb to define ResponseSet
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:503:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `each'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/activesupport-3.0.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/my_stuff/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@my_project/gems/railties-3.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :002 > rs = MyCompany::ResponseSet.new
 => []
```

Also, adding

```
require 'response_set'
```

at the top of response_set_spec.rb allows those tests to run. But no such thing is necessary for smart_set_spec.rb.

The following is in place in application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/**/"]
```

Now, I understand that Rails has some sort of opinion on how file structure should match namespace structure for these types of things, and we have restructured our modules and files towards this end. It SEEMS to have fixed the issue (although we were seeing some other weird load errors for a while when we ran the full test suite - these have mysteriously gone away). Nonetheless everyone here is baffled and not a little annoyed that Rails is being so inconsistent and we would like to know why. As you can see there are two files that are identical as far as namespacing and file structure are concerned, being treated completely differently. In fact we have about a dozen other files in the top level of 'lib' with similar namespacing that have never caused any problems. Can anyone explain what the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 28):

We had a similar issue which, after digging, turned out to be caused by the changes in Rails 3.x and `autoload_paths`.

Our case appeared only in test (`RAILS_ENV=test`). When Rails was loading the controllers, it scrambled about looking for each controller's matching model (due to a ActionController::Base.wrap_parameters set in an initializer). Eventually it wound down to the method mentioned above (load_missing_constant). Since our autoload_paths included both lib and lib/**, Rails pulled in all the files from all the subdirectories under lib. Unfortunately, it appears to ignore the implied namespace when loading from subdirectories. It expected foo/base.rb to define `Base` vs. `Foo::Base`. That seems to be the core flaw: `load_missing_constant` invokes `search_for_file` which returns any file whose name matches (e.g., in my example, foo/base.rb was returned as it matched base.rb).

It's hard to say if this is an error in Rails - in that it violates the namespace-to-directory mapping assumed by Ruby - or a misuse of autoload_paths.

We have worked around this for now by removing `lib/**` from our `autoload_paths` and adding the necessary require statements to application.rb.

Comment: I had to the same thing.  I think you're on the right track about the root problem.... surprised nobody else is complaining about this.

Comment: Rails is beginning to annoy me.

Comment: @Zabba: Yeah, seems to be turning into a straight jacket.

Comment: @Zabba 6 months into rails dev and I'm fed up with it. I want a real language/framework.

Comment: Seems like the issue is including both lib/ and lib/**. By using lib/** each nested folder is treated as a root search folder so a file in lib/foo/base.rb would logically be expected to include Base. If you only include lib/ then foo/base would include Foo::Base.

Comment: I found that just explicitly including my lib like this worked: config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/mylib) whereas everything else didn't.

Comment: I've dealt with something similar in Java (e.g ClassNotFound exception, or NoClassDefFoundError...), and now, here come Rails.

Answer (score 4):

I looked into the rails source and there is a

```
if file_path && ! loaded.include?(File.expand_path(file_path)) # We found a matching file to load
  require_or_load file_path
  raise LoadError, "Expected #{file_path} to define #{qualified_name}" unless local_const_defined?(from_mod, const_name)
  return from_mod.const_get(const_name)
elsif ...
```

clause in `load_missing_constant` method. I may guess that as `require_or_load` is called before `raise`, this might be a reason that on the second call in your example there is no error...

It would be interesting to see a minimal example where two files with identical structure behave differently.
In your place i would make a copy of the application and would keep removing parts from it while the inconsistent behavior is present to see the minimal inconsistent example.

P.S. I have submitted a similar question here: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2376956

Comment: Thank you Alexey. That does look suspicious. It seems to me that raising the Exception should depend on weather 'require_or_load' was successful. But then again I am not very familiar with the labyrinth that is Rails guts.

Comment: @Nick, apparently the exception is raised when, after loading the file, the constant is still not defined. In your case, it seems that the file is expected to define `ResponseSet` while it defines `MyCompany::ResponseSet` (this is how it looks to me, but i am not a specialist). The inconsistency is what is the most strange. Are your sure that you did not simplify the original problem? Maybe `MyCompany::SmartSet` is in `/lib/my_company/smart_set.rb` and not just `/lib/smart_set.rb`? I have submitted a [bug report at GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2572) about a similar issue.

Comment: Nope. The file structures were identical. We spent a couple hours checking every possible difference we could think of. The only differences are with the actual implementation of each class (i.e. attributes and methods) but none of that should affect how the files are loaded!

Comment: This is interesting. I think that to submit a bug report to rails, a minimal example is needed (how to recreate the problem starting from a new blank application).

Answer (score 4):

Was pointed in the correct direction by Brendan, check your autoload_paths.  I had a similar error and this was the culprit for me in application.rb :

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/[a-z]*"]
```

My app was not happy once I started using modules for the models along with having sub-directories.  I changed mine to autoload just the non-module directories :

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/aaaaaaaaa"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/models/bbbbbbbbb"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've suffered from the very same problem with namespaced classes being autoloaded incorrectly. This is the clue to solve it (from Brendan's answer):

> Since our autoload_paths included both lib and lib/**, Rails pulled in all the files from all the subdirectories under lib. Unfortunately, it appears to ignore the implied namespace when loading from subdirectories. It expected foo/base.rb to define Base vs. Foo::Base. That seems to be the core flaw: load_missing_constant invokes search_for_file which returns any file whose name matches (e.g., in my example, foo/base.rb was returned as it matched base.rb).

And I've solved it by moving all my namespaced classes, named `Events::Something`, into `app/components/events/*` and creating a file `app/components/events.rb` with the following content:

```
%w(file1 file2 ...).each do |file|  
  require "events/#{file}"
end
```

And while this is a little bit manual, it works both for application, console and test modes.

Answer (score 0):

Another point worth to notice is that whether you have the correct path in services folder.

By correct path, I mean

engine_name/app/services/engine_name/your_service.rb

I have accidentally forgot engine_name folder inside services, and got this strange behaviour.