# Expected to define. When calling class inside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I new to rails. I have a setup in the lib directory like so:

```
lib/
   blog/
     core/
        search/
            base.rb
```

The base.rb defines the Base class as well:

```
module Blog
  module Core
    module Search
      class Base

        attr_accessor :properties

        def initialize(params)
          @properties = {}
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have the following code in my application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

When I include it in posts controller I get following errors:

```
LoadError in PostsController#index

Expected /home/usr/code/blog/lib/blog/core/search/base.rb to define Base
```

Any idea? I'm using rails 3.2.5 with RVM. Thank you for every advice.

**UPDATED:** Added my full stack:

```
Started GET "/admin/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-08 21:06:18 +0800

LoadError (Expected /home/usr/code/blog/lib/blog/core/search/base.rb to define Base):
  app/controllers/admin/base_controller.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/admin/posts_controller.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'


  Rendered /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/usr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails-3.2.5/gems/actionpack-3.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (7.0ms)
```

Comment: Any suggestion and answer for this??

Comment: What are you including in your posts controller exactly?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Here is require 'blog/core/search/base'

Comment: This might give some clues. I don't know the correct answer, but seems someone else stumbled upon the same error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081782/inconsistent-loaderror-behavior-with-lib-namespacing-autoloading

Comment: When I change Base class to Base module it's working fine. Why?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same problem. It comes from the fact that you try to load **/lib/blog/core/search/base.rb** directly in **application.rb** with `/lib/**/`

**Error I had:**

```
Expected /[...]/myapp/lib/durative/base.rb to define Base (LoadError)
```

**Directory structure:**

```
lib/
 --durative/
   --base.rb
```

**base.rb:**

```
module Durative
  class Base
    def initialize(config)
       @config = {}
    end
    #...
  end
end
```

**application.rb:**

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

#### Here are the changes I made to make it work

**Directory structure:**

```
lib/
 --durative.rb **(added)**
 --durative/
   --base.rb
```

**durative.rb:**

```
require 'durative/base'
```

**base.rb** (no change)

**application.rb (changed):**

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/"]
```

Tell us if it worked for you too.

Comment: That indeed solved my problem as well! Anybody knows why there is this error message? A bit more background on double definitions might be very instructive... (just in case someone knows)

Comment: I think load and require work differently when it involves nested modules and classes. When auto_load_path loads the nested file, it expects the base class to be defined directly, not nested inside modules.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. The problem was because I was including subdirs without including their parent lib dir:

```
# did not work
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/foo)
```

and

```
# in lib/foo/my_class.rb
module Foo
  class MyClass
  end
end
```

Foo::MyClass would return Expected to define MyClass

adding the lib dir to config.autoload_paths fixes the problem

```
# worked
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/lib/foo)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add:
`require base.rb` 
in your environment.rb file.

source:
http://icebergist.com/posts/expected-xrb-to-define-x-loaderror

Answer (score 1):

Also, one thing to check is that your controller is named appropriately.

For instance, make sure that your posts_controller.rb looks like this on the first line

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
```

I have made mistakes where I copied a controller and tracked it down to not changing the controller classes name

Answer (score 0):

If you have that deeply hidden class then access it this way:

```
Blog::Core::Search::Base.new 'foo'
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But result is same :(

Comment: @Zeck I'd created exactly the same structure as you had and after running in my console `Blog::Core::Search::Base.new 'foo'` I got `#<Blog::Core::Search::Base:0x297c0d8 @properties={}>`. No `require` needed, by the way.

Comment: Thank you. I'm tried but no luck. Can you push your code to github?

Comment: @Zeck Are you sure you're calling it **not simply** `Base.new`?

Comment: Yes. I'm very sure. I'm following spree's search logic. Here is the base search class [lib/spree/core/search/base.rb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/search/base.rb) and view [spree/core/app/views/spree/shared/_search.html.erb](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/views/spree/shared/_search.html.erb). But no luck :(

Comment: @Zeck One more assumption: replace in application.rb your line with `config.autoload_paths += %W[#{config.root}/lib]` to prevent deep searching and use fully qualified name to access deeply hidden stuff. **Don't forget to restart your app!**

Answer (score 0):

My error with this was that I had

```
app/
  controllers/
      projects/
          some_controller.rb
      projects_controller.rb
```

I was trying to keep my app organized and, when having a namespace - was splitting up the controller. Unfortunately it looks like Rails would randomly jump between the two and there would be conflicts causing the error in OP.

Solution:
Rename your sub-directory and adjust any routes.