# 'Expected to define' error calling lib through model, fine when called directly in console (autoloading)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

My structure is something like (base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948779/expected-to-define-when-calling-class-inside-a-module)):

```
# lib/myapp/uploader.rb
require 'uploader/base'

# lib/myapp/uploader/base.rb
module MyApp
  module Uploader
    class Base
    end
  end
end

# app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def test
    MyApp::Uploader::Base
  end
end
```

Called directly in console:

```
$ MyApp::Uploader::Base #> MyApp::Uploader::Base
```

Through model in console:

```
$ Model.new.test
LoadError: Expected <snip>/lib/myapp/uploader.rb to define Uploader
```

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check my updated answer below

Comment: Why the downvotes?? Is this not a legitimate question??

Comment: i didnt put downvote mate. You the one put to my answer. I never put downvote to any. Thanks for you cancelled the downvote to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer:

In this case, you missing the require in your Model

So add the following in your `app/models/model.rb`

```
# app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  require Rails.root.join('lib').join('myapp').join('uploader').join('base').to_s 

  def test
    MyApp::Uploader::Base
  end
end
```

Comment: Trying to do this with autoloading, sorry.

Comment: What do you mean by autoloading. Try without `to_s` if you want just an object.

Comment: `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/myapp/uploader/base"` But I'm sorry, this is just not what I'm looking for. I'm trying to autoload. If you don't know what that means, see first link in my post.

Comment: then you should post your question correctly. Before you just explained about the error. now you changed your question.

Comment: Check the Help Manual about how to post questions. It's might helpful for your future.

Comment: I forgot to mention autoloading, that's it. Hardly changing the question.