# Ruby "wrapper" class to represent a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I've found that if I create a module, I have to create a "wrapper class" for it to work in certain circumstances (actually Resque-pool in my case, but I think it's relevant elsewhere too, even though it worked in regular Unicorn without needing it). By wrapper class, I mean if I create:

```
models/
  posts/
    selfie.rb
```

I will get a "Expected selfie.rb to define Posts::Selfie" unless I also create models/posts.rb containing "require posts/selfie.rb". (Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11001022/18706)

My question is, should this be done for every module under models, controllers, etc? And is there a name for this kind of class, or any reference info about it?

Comment: actually its only true in dev mode