# How can I omit the module name when using autoloaded classes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I've got the following files:

```
|- app
|  |- helpers
|  |  |- application_helper.rb
|- config
|- |- application.rb
|- lib
|  |- my_module
|  |  |- my_class.rb
```

I'm trying to make Rails autoload `my_module`. In `application.rb` I set

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

I've also managed to obtain the secret knowledge that in order for autoloading to work, the names of modules and classes must match the names of directories and files, so `my_class.rb` looks like this:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    # ...
  end
end
```

Now I want to use `MyClass` in my `application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  include MyModule

  def some_method(active_entry = nil)
    someobject = MyClass.new
    #...
  end

end
```

But I'm getting an error

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::MyClass
```

In order to make this code work I must replace

```
someobject = MyClass.new
```

with

```
someobject = MyModule::MyClass.new
```

which is ugly. I thought that the `include` would work like a C++ `using namespace`, C# `using` or Java `import` but apparently it doesn't. So is there any equivalent to the above statements in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ChuckE was close, what you need to do is change config.autoload_paths to

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

The following works for me

- create directory `app/lib/my_module`
- create file in there called `my_module.rb`

Contents of file:

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    def self.hello
      puts "Hello"
    end
  end
end
```

- ensure `config.autoload_paths` is as noted above
- run `rails console`

Output:

```
[tharrison@mbpro:~/Sites/test] rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3-p194 :001 > include MyModule
 => Object 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > MyClass.hello
Hello
 => nil
```

I haven't tried this from the app, but cannot see why it would be any different than running from the rails console.

Oh, and credit where credit is due: got this from [Best way to load module/class from lib folder in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3)

Comment: Thanks, it sort of works. There's only one problem left: this, and the uglier solution from your previous comment, starts working always after a few failed attempts after the server is started. For every class in `my_module` (alright, there are two of them actually) I get a one-time error `expected (...)/lib/my_module/my_class.rb to define MyClass`. Then my app works flawlessly until I restart the server. What the hell?

Comment: Also works from within my app without errors.  (Changed `puts "Hello"` to `"Hello"` and then added `include MyModule` to a controller, and in the index method added `logger.debug "Output from MyClass.hello is #{MyClass.hello}"`, which shows in the log when I run.  Are your files all named correctly?

Comment: Well, I reproduced your steps, creating a new Rails project, and still got the weird error at the first call of `MyClass.hello`. I'm currently upgrading from ruby-1.9.3-p286 to ruby-1.9.3-p327 to see if it helps, though I must say I doubt it. Anyway, if you don't get the error and I do, then I suppose something must be messed up with my installation of RoR :/

Comment: Very skeptical that newer ruby will help.  All of what makes this work is relatively basic ruby functionality that has been around forever.

Comment: This error is starting to drive me mad. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081782/inconsistent-loaderror-behavior-with-lib-namespacing-autoloading) shed some on the problem to me - it seems that Rails, for some reason, treats lib/my_module folder as root and expects to find class `MyClass` there, instead of `MyModule::MyClass`. Removing the `module` declarations from files solves the problem. I would rather have these classes in a module, but this solution must do for now, or I'll go insane trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

try this:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib"]
```

Comment: No difference. Though I'll keep this syntax, I'm not a great fan of `%W` TBH.

Comment: well, for me it seems that the sub-directories of lib are not getting included, thought that would work. go to your console and use $: to see if your sub-directory is being referenced.

Comment: @kamilk -- you need to restart the server for this to re-init.  Assuming you have done that, try changing `%W(#{config.root/lib)` to `%W(#{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/lib/my_module)`.  The difference in what @ChuckE proposes is that adding `Dir` causes Rails to search the entire subtree, whereas the simple array syntax just enumerates specific directories to check.  So I would think his solution should work.

Comment: OK, I have confirmed that adding another path to the `%W` form works, and that `Dir["..."]` doesn't work as ChuckE and I thought it would.  Searching for more elegant solution :-)